# FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory) error when trying to get multiple Files in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to get multiple Files received from an ArrayList, but I'm getting a FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory) error. I get the Uris and convert them to files. Then I pass the files in an ArrayList to another method. So far so good, but apparently the files are not being added to the entity.

Getting the Uris from a multiple images picker:

```
private final ArrayList<Uri> uri = new ArrayList<>();
...

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pictures: "), 1001);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        uri.clear();
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    uri.add(data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSend) {
        syncDataToServer(uri);
    }
}

public DataResponse syncDataToServer(ArrayList<Uri> uris) {
    try {
        ArrayList<File> fs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < uris.size(); i++) {
            if (uris != null)
            fs.add(new File(uris.get(i).getPath()));
        }

        DataResponse data = uploadFiles("https://endpoint", params, fs);

        assert data != null;
        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The following method receives the data but generates the error when trying to generate the HttpResponse.

```
public static DataResponse uploadFiles(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params, ArrayList<File> files) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new 
        MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        FileBody fileBody = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            if(files.get(i) != null)
                fileBody = new FileBody(files.get(i));

            if(fileBody != null)
                reqEntity.addPart("uploaded_file" + i, fileBody);
        }

        if(params != null) {
            for(NameValuePair pair : params) {
                StringBody stringB = new StringBody(pair.getValue(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                reqEntity.addPart(pair.getName(), stringB);
            }
        }

        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream source = getResponseEntity.getContent();


        JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
        f.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(f);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        DataResponse data;
        try  {
            data = mapper.readValue(source, DataResponse.class);
            return data;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
2022-08-03 09:45:03.815 18170-18553/com.chillihaze.deskeep E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
Process: com.chillihaze.deskeep, PID: 18170
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.chillihaze.events.Teste.syncDataToServer(Teste.java:257)
    at com.chillihaze.events.Teste.access$000(Teste.java:46)
    at com.chillihaze.events.Teste$1.onAsyncTaskDoInBackground(Teste.java:241)
    at com.libraries.asynctask.MGAsyncTask.doInBackground(MGAsyncTask.java:44)
    at com.libraries.asynctask.MGAsyncTask.doInBackground(MGAsyncTask.java:10)
```

Comment: Needs more information on the exception details, you've not indicated where issue is nor the format of the uris.

Comment: Still no information on FileNotFoundException. Printing names of files and testing `file.exists()` usually tells you enough about the problem.

Comment: I have this line in logcat: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /0/1/content:/media/external/images/media/38/ORIGINAL/NONE/848352313 (No such file or directory)

Comment: @DuncG the condition if (files.get(i).exists()) return false.